# Proper handling of confirmation page in PHP

Tags: php

I have a sign up page written in php, that goes to a confirmation page after processing. In the confirmation/ thank you page there is a 3rd party script that counts the number of successful registrants. how would I limit the script to be loaded per successful registration?

Answer (score 0):

Ask your thrd party script author? As noone here knows how it works.
If it utilizes session mechanism, you can use sessions then.